# SecurityCritical on overriden function InitializeLifetimeService has not affect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

I'm running into some Medium trust issues with a few libraries. I'm able to reproduce the error with a sample and referencing that in my MVC probject. I'm trying to get pass this problem but don't understand what I'm missing.

I keep getting this error:

> Inheritance security rules violated
>   while overriding member:
>   'Temp.Class1.InitializeLifetimeService()'.
>   Security accessibility of the
>   overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method
>   being overriden.

I think understand the security transparency error above, and I make sure my method is the same as the overriding method. Here is my class:

```
public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject
{

    [SecurityCritical]
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And I am still getting the same error as above.

Have been adding and removing this line with no effect:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]
```

Reading other articles all I have to do is to add the SecurityCritical attribute to the method, but it does not seem to have any affect.

Any ideas, or something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Medium trust web application, only GACed binaries are granted full trust permissions.  If your binary is bin-deployed, it is partial-trust and transparent.  [MSDN has a good write-up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102.aspx) of what transparent code can and cannot do.  Importantly, **declaring a [SecurityCritical] member is a full-trust only operation.**  If your bin-deployed library contains a member annotated with [SecurityCritical], the CLR will ignore that annotation.

If your library is designed to be bin-deployed and runnable in Medium trust, you cannot override or otherwise access a [SecurityCritical] member.  Consider reworking your library so as not to call these methods.

Comment: Aaahh, that makes sense, rereading the link I noticed: "In addition, transparent methods cannot override critical virtual methods or implement critical interface methods", and your bin-deployed explanation makes this understandable. Wish it was a bit clearer in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: "only GACed binaries are granted full trust" is only partially true. They are granted full trust by default, but you can configure your site to trust certain assemblies - even bin deployed - without putting them in the GAC. http://xheo.com/knowledge-base/deploylx/licensing/full-trust-required-in-asp-net

Comment: "Consider reworking your library so as not to call these methods." - apparently Levi doesn't know what InitializeLifetimeService is for. "Your" library doesn't call it. The .NET framework itself calls it. Its purpose is (roughly) to prevent premature garbage collection of a MarshalByRefObject. If you don't override InitializeLifetimeService, your object will be collected after 6 minutes. Apparently Microsoft thinks partially-trusted remote objects should always last 6 minutes. At least it should be possible to keep the object alive by calling it every minute or so...